# How to change the result of fmt.Println with a prefix argument

Tags: go, println

I have the following code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    P("1","2","3",0)
}

func P(prefix string,a ...interface{}){
    fmt.Println(prefix,a)
}
```

The result is:

```
1 [2 3 0]
```

But I would like to have one of the following results instead:

```
1 2 3 0
[1 2 3 0]
```

In other words: all arguments are of same importance, so no argument should be handled in a special way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evgeny's solution (changing the function signature) is best, but if you can't change the function signature for whatever reason:

```
func P(prefix string, a ...interface{}) {
    toPrint := []interface{}{prefix}
    toPrint = append(toPrint, a...)
    fmt.Println(toPrint...)  // 1 2 3 0
    // without the `...` you get [1 2 3 0]
}
```

Or you can just `fmt.Printf` in a loop:

```
func P(prefix string, a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Print(prefix)
    for _, aa := range a {
        fmt.Printf(" %v", aa)
    }
    fmt.Println()  // for your final newline
}
```

Of course the even *better* solution involves removing all doubt about the type you're passing in. `interface{}` means nothing -- define a type and stick with it!

Answer (score 1):

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    P("1","2","3",0)
}

func P(a ...interface{}){
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The result is:

```
[1 2 3 0]
```